# I have error with docker-compose (exited with code 243)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm have dockers error(exited with code 243), after run my docker-compose file
My docker file:

```
FROM node:16
ARG stage
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./env/${stage}.env .
COPY ./env/test.env .
EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm run start --prefix ./
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change node version from node:16 to node:16.14.2
It's work for me

```
FROM node:16.14.2
ARG stage
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./env/${stage}.env .
COPY ./env/test.env .
EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm run start --prefix ./
```

Comment: Same here, for some weird reason I was running v16.17.1 and concurrently would crash with an exit code 243. Downgrading to v16.4.2 solved the issue.